# yup validation input dependence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Hi all I have following validation:

```
const questionAddValidation = Yup.object().shape({

  questions: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object({
      question: Yup.string().required().min(100)
       
      level: Yup.string().required().when("question", {
                 is: (value) => value.length > 0,
                 then: Yup.string().required(),
              }),

      answers: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object({
          answer: Yup.string().required().min(1).when("question", {
                 is: (value) => value && value.length > 0,
                 then: Yup.string().required(),
              }),
        })
      ),
    })
  ),
```

What I want to do is that if user will type something in `question` input for  other inputs should work yup `required()` method.

I try  following:

```
  is: (value) => value.length > 0
```

But it not working,
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
can u please help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just remove `required()` before `when`

```
 level: Yup.string().when("question", {
    is: (value) => value.length > 0,
    then: Yup.string().required(),
 }),
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but still not working  `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`